# Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't recognize front audio jack

Tags: 20.04, sound, soundcard, jack, audio-jack

On my PC I have two audio jacks - rear and front. Rear works good and without any problem. And connected to the audiocard straightly. The front jack connected to the audiocard trough motherboard via cabels. I couldn't resolve this problem on Ubuntu and decided to install Windows on my other SSD and try to use it. After some manipulations on windows settings I could use the front jack.

On ubuntu I did every possible thing I found in word wide web. Each question with its answers on askubuntu didn't help me.

I don't see the front jack in ubuntu settings. When I do some changes in pulseaudio and soft like it I can use the front jack, but both of jacks have the same signal, I mean if U turn the music on, I'll listen it via headphone and speakers :) And if I reboot the front jack will not work again. Need to do the same manipulations in pulseaudio again.

What I want: to have the front jack option in settings so I could select which jack I need to use now. It's usefull to listen a music via speakers but calls and meetings via headphones. I change everytime the device from rear audio jack

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, can you paste the output of `pactl list sinks`

Comment: Hi, thanks. Here is it: https://pastebin.com/h5YVdyQn

Comment: I see two devices ( 2 sinks), one is a built-in audio chip onboard and another is HDMI perhaps on your display. When you use a rear jack, the front jack should be suspended. I don't see speakers on the list, these should be connected with your amplifiers via Lineout. That makes front-jack unavailable. `sudo apt install pavucontrol` you can manipulate visually. If you want to use speakers and headphones independently you should connect speakers on the display and headphones on the front jack. If your display doesn't have a jack, then you can buy a USB DAC which provides excellent sounds.

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka ok, thanks. Will try and get back here